# How to unittest the side effects of a method in c++?

Tags: c++, unit-testing

In real C++ project most methods has side effects, besides returning a value and changing the output parameter.

```
// For examle
bool A::doA()
{
    bool isSuccess = true;
    isSuccess &= b.doB();
    isSuccess &= c.doC();
    this->a++;
    return isSuccess;
}
```

The side effects of above method includes calling 2 methods and changing member variable a.
However, when writing unittest for above method, I see most people just check the return value and ignoring the side effects, which does reach 100% code coverage.
But I think such unittest is silly for 2 reasons:
1. The main function of method doA is the side effects, not the return value.
2. If doA has void return value(which is common in real code), you can't even write a unittest such way.

By Google, I find some way to test the side effects:
1.mock b and c, and check if doB and doC  is called.
2.check value of member variable a through some technique.
But I think such unittest is not good for 2 reasons:
1.There will be so many mockings and time costed. Also, it seems silly to just check if a method is called.
2.It depends on implementation of method instead of interface, if implementation changes, unittest need to change. And I hear someone say unittest should be black-box test.

So how do you hanlde such problem in real project?

Comment: Presumably, the code in the function under test calls another function either to use it to calculate something or for its side effects. If it's the latter, just check that the side effect took place. That's not an implementation detail; it's part of the effect of the function.

Comment: The SOLID principle advises to separate concerns. Each class is designed as a mockable small module, and this helps you to unittest each one. Having multiple side effects is not a good practice that violates SOLID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general:

Tests always verify some kind of publicly observable behaviour. It doesn’t matter if that behaviour is a return value or a side effect. The API and/or documentation of cour code under test must make it clear what exactly the side effects are. If the side effects don’t exhibit any publicly observable behaviour, they are purely an internal implementation detail and are not relevant for the test; also they shouldn’t be part of the public API or its documentation.

**As a rule of thumb, don’t test for things you only know about because you looked at the implementation of your code under test.**

Regarding your example:

If `doB()` or `doC()` cause relevant side effects, those are part of `doA()`’s observable behaviour. Check for the effects themselves. Whether they where caused directly by `doA()` or by another function called inside of `doA()` is an implementation detail and thus irrelevant for your test.

Maybe an effect of “doing A” is adding that particular `A` object to a registry. Then the right thing to do is to check that the object was registered.